# Cisco 500 switch

Tags: networking, troubleshooting

I want to remotely access Cisco 500 switches via TELNET and WEB BASED from a server. I dont know the ip addresses for Cisco 500 switches which are configured as backbone which the ip address assigned on the network is static ip address. Specifically I want to get their configuations inorder to get their specified assigned vlans on the network. I know the ip addresses for their specified cisco 500 switches' gateways. I know that cisco 500 switches can be accesses through web. Is there other ways to solve the problem apart from going onsite and connect to the cisco 500 switches using network cable since cisco 500 swithes dont have console ports? Please assist..greg

Comment: I'm unclear if you know that the switch has been configured with an IP address, but you're not sure what it is, or if it's not configured (yet), or if it's configured with an IP address that ought not to belong there...?

Comment: Thanks Nevile..that's exactly my problem. I'm doing a network audit. I just joined the networks team and I'm starting from scratch..there's not much information from this particular network that I'm doing the audit..cheers

Comment: Do you believe it probably is configured properly, and you'd just like to figure out what its IP address is?

Answer (score 0):

If the router that your cisco 500 is also a cisco, you might be able to use [Cisco Discovery Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_Discovery_Protocol) to get its information.

`show cdp neighbours` ought to give you some information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Remotely access a PC in the network connected to the switch.

The switch probably has an IP on that VLAN Interface.

**Ping to broadcast ip** address of the current network from the PC. All PCs are, by default, configured not to respond to broadcast pings, as a security measure. So the only responses you will get would be from the Switch ( and maybe from a router too if any)

Once you get the responses from an IP, try to telnet to that IP.

Let us know if this works

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to just directly connect to them on site.

While it is a good idea to assign an IP address to a vlan interface, it may not have been done as technically switches only need to perform L2 functions.

If you don't have any documentation on the network, you might be able to check the DHCP server to see if the vlans are for some reason configured to get an IP from DHCP.

You can also do a ping sweep to get info on what IP addresses respond and depending on the program used to do the ping sweep, you can get info on what OS the machines are running and such. I think Nmap provides this functionality, not sure though.
Quick google search should give you a list of tools.

Hope you find a way to do this.

Also you would need to do the ping sweep from inside the network, not out.